# Why Java File.createNewFile requires prefix to be at least three characters long?

Tags: java, file

According to [java.io.File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), the prefix to create a temp file must be at least 3 characters long. Why does java API have this restriction? See following javadoc (emphasis mine)

> public static File **createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException**
>
> Creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using the given prefix and suffix to generate its name. Invoking this method is equivalent to invoking createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null).
>
> The Files.createTempFile method provides an alternative method to create an empty file in the temporary-file directory. Files created by that method may have more restrictive access permissions to files created by this method and so may be more suited to security-sensitive applications.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **prefix - The prefix string to be used in generating the file's name; must be at least three characters long**
>
> suffix - The suffix string to be used in generating the file's name; may be null, in which case the suffix ".tmp" will be used
>
> Returns: An abstract pathname denoting a newly-created empty file
>
> Throws: **IllegalArgumentException - If the prefix argument contains fewer than three characters**
>
> IOException - If a file could not be created
>
> SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method does not allow a file to be created

For example this prefix is invalid as it has only two characters

```
// Throws IllegalArgumentException: Prefix string "te" too short: length must be at least 3
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("te", ".tmp");
```

While this prefix is valid because it has 4 characters:

```
// Creates temp file test14287484991844360415.tmp
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".tmp");
```

The new java API ([java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)) does not have this restriction, and works whit prefix shorter than 3 characters, so what is the reason why the old java File API requires prefix to be at least three characters long?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic for Stack Overflow, but also off topic for the options under Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @hfontanez Why? Seems like a reasonable question to me. Although why-based questions often drift into opinion territory, this was clearly a deliberate decision that served a specific purpose.

Comment: @shmosel It is a reasonable question. I never said it wasn't. But I don't think it belongs here. I have seen other similarly reasonable questions being shut down for being "off topic". So, I exercised my judgment and did what I think is right. Notice that I didn't downvote the question. I do not operate that way.

Comment: I think this question should be left open, for the reason mentioned by shmosel. The JavaDocs suggest that this was not a kind of "because the API authors designed it this way", but it rather suggests that this was a deliberate choice.

Comment: @shmosel I think when it comes to "api design choices" like this - unless it's clearly documented, it begins to reach into the area of "opinion" - I tend to agree, while it's a reasonable question, I'm not convinced it's within scope for SO.  When you have a look at the source code, there is no explanation of "why", so unless we happen to have the original author(s) of the code, we can only "guess" at the reasoning

Answer (score -4):

Likely a limitation that was on older hardware or an older version of an operating system Java works on. You might be able to go around the limitation by putting a space after the prefix to make it longer, like this:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("te ", ".tmp");
```

However, I have not used `File.createTempFile()` before, only creating permanent files, such as:

```
File file = new File("te.tmp");
file.createNewFile();
```

And I have had no reason to make a file shorter than 3 characters, so I don't know whether or not it would work with a permanent file. Let me know if this helps.